# Android: Launch Firefox from within application

Tags: android, firefox, android-intent, android-activity

just wondering if anyone know the correct intent to launch Firefox's Mobile Browser. I can't find it anywhere, so I was hoping someone here would know.
Thanks

Comment: Why Firefox specifically? Why not a general "browser" intent? What if the user doesn't have FF?

Comment: Cant you just launch browser? And on handset if you set Firefox as the default browser, it should be launched.

Comment: This is for a business sales app, so they will always be run on the same tablet, with the same browser. Right now I have the browser chooser that comes up, but that's kind of annoying and I'd like to streamline it a little further.

Comment: what I've been doing is omermuhammed's suggestion of setting the default browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will create an intent for Firefox:

```
String url = "http://example.com/";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
intent.setAction("org.mozilla.gecko.BOOKMARK");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("args", "--url=" + url)
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to launch firefox anymore but this works!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
 this.startActivity(intent);
```