# Android Intent: Open link in Firefox regardless of user's default browser?

Tags: android, firefox, android-intent

I am trying to make an intent that will open **com.mozilla.firefox** with my link and ignoring the default intent handler for **`.ACTION_VIEW`**

My current logic is this:

```
        Uri uri = formatURL(url); //Turns my string into a URI formatted correctly

        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        intent.setPackage("com.mozilla.firefox");

        contextActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

This seems like it should work, but instead does nothing (compared to removing line #3, which opens in Chrome, my default browser). Is it possible to specifically target another app for an intent?

Comment: The answers here solved my issue! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014811/android-launch-firefox-from-within-application

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
intent.setClassName("packageName", "className");
```

But it's better to query the activities that can open the intent and launch it

```
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                        PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);

 for (ResolveInfo info :
                activities) {
     if( info.activityInfo.packageName.contains("com.mozilla.firefox")){
           //launch firefox: 
          intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName,info.activityInfo.name);
          startActivity(intent);         
          }
 }
```

so if Firefox is not installed you can start your default intent.