# React native Expo intent open app passing parameters

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firefox, android-intent

I have to make sure to open an app, which is installed on the device by passing the parameters.
The application in this case is firefox.

I found something like that but I don't know if it can help me: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940459)

I found this on Expo but I don't know if it does what I'm looking for:
[Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/#type-intentparams)

Some advice?

Answer (score 0):

The expo-intent-launcher library has an interface IntentLauncherParams, which must be implemented.
To implement the interface you need to create a component in typescript.
[See: React Native TypeScript](https://The%20expo-intent-launcher%20library%20has%20an%20interface%20IntentLauncherParams,%20which%20must%20be%20implemented.%20To%20implement%20the%20interface%20you%20need%20to%20create%20a%20component%20in%20typescript.) and [See: Expo Typescript](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/typescript/)

1. Create class IntentParams that implements IntentLauncherParams. I did it using constructor to pass some defaults that I needed in my case.

```js
class IntentParams implements IntentLauncherParams {
  type?: string;
  category?: string;
  data?: string;
  flags?: number;
  packageName?: string;
  className?: string;
  extra?: Record<string, any>;
  constructor(flags?: number, extra?: Record<string, any>) {
    this.flags = flags;
    this.extra = extra;
  }
}
```

2. Create function Foo() to start activity

```js
const Foo = () => {
    try {
      const transaction = { requestedAmount: amount, currency: currency };
      const transactionJson = JSON.stringify(transaction);

      const extra: Record<string, any> = {
        extra1: "extra1parameter",
        extra2: "extra2parameter",
        extra3: transactionJson,
      };
      const params = new IntentParams(_MY_FLAG_, extra);

      startActivityAsync(_MY_ACTIVITY_, params)
        .then((t) => {
          console.log(t);
          setData(t.data);
        })
        .catch((err) =>
          console.error(
            `Foo inline: ${JSON.stringify(
              err.request
            )}: ${err}`
          )
        );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        `Foo: ${JSON.stringify(
          error.request
        )}: ${error}`
      );
    }
  };
```

3. Run function from desired place in your component.
4. Please remember to import library at the beginning

```js
import { IntentLauncherParams, startActivityAsync } from "expo-intent-launcher";
```

I hope it will help you.